# QT5 - Bluetooth Scanner Example cannot pair detected device

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth, qt5, fedora-21

I am trying to run a Bluetooth Scanner Example located on the site below:

[Bluetooth Scanner Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-btscanner-example.html)

Anytime the application detects a device and I try to pair, I receive the error message below:
`qt.bluetooth.bluez: Failed to create pairing "org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed"`

I have searched on for possible ways to pair and connect to bluetooth devices through qt5 but I don't seem to get any promising result.

I am trying to create a GUI bluetooth application that can detect, pair and connect to the detected device as a project. Therefore, I would be glad if I can be pointed in the right direction in troubleshooting this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is not an open bar. Such errors may be because:

- you did not provided the correct credential (typically a PIN code) when trying to pair,
- the device is already paired to something else,
- the device is not yet paired but refused to pair with you, for example a smartphone may get some pairing request, then the phone user will get prompted on the phone screen to accept it or not.

You should conduct your trials with your own phone, were you will have complete control (set the credentials, be unpaired, accept the pairing request).

Comment: Actually, I tried with my own phone. The application fails to display the `pairingConfirmation` dialog prior to initiating the pair.

Comment: Then maybe your application does not announce itself with the proper profile (bluetooth is not a generic all-data communication model, it goes by profiles which could be describe as application classes). A phone should always be interested in a HSP profile (HeadSet profile). If you do a bluetooth scan on your phone (warning: it is longer than a Wi-Fi scan), do you see your application?

Comment: Yes I am able to detect the system on my phone when I enable `visibility` on the system. I believe the problem has to do with the source codes in the link I posted above. There is a part that is missing but I am unable to figure it out

Comment: And I'd bet there's no headset icon displayed for your system on your phone screen. The Qt sample code you started with looks like a minimal "hello bluetooth world", and as far as I can tell it does its job. You'll need to dig deeper. From what I can see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothuuid.html) there are some stuff, at least enum, for HSP profile. Another profile you could use is HFP, for "Hand Free Profile".

Comment: My main concerned is that, I wanted to see how `pairing` is done using qt5 since with bluez 5 using gdbus, I can pair with devices in console mode but I am unable to do same in GUI mode using gtk+-3.0. Therefore, I decided to try qt5 and I am facing issues.

Comment: I am trying to connect to bluetooth printer using KUbuntu 15.04 and Qt app. I have been coding bluetooth connection by taking this example as reference, and I am just wondering, how does one programmaticaly send PIN code to printer?